# send a GetFeatureInfo to Geoserver over a time range

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I want query geoserver about [FeatureInfo](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) from a set of images temporally spaced. How I should build this route?

Comment: Thanks to SO's reputation system I cannot comment, only post an answer. I know this is a very old thread, but would you kindly post your complete GetFeatureInfo request, since adding e.g. `&TIME=2021-07-15T00:00:00.000Z/2021-07-15T23:00:00.000Z` to a request only returns the value for the latest time. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/services/wms/time.html) where time support for GetMap in Geoserver is described, which seems to be available from version 2.2. You could check, if using time parameter for GetFeatureInfo on a time-enabled wms will work, too.

Otherwise, I am pretty sure, there is time support with the [thredds WMS](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/v4.6/tds/reference/WMS.html)/ [ncWMS](http://www.resc.rdg.ac.uk/trac/ncWMS/), where you can expose netCDF files containing time series data. Maybe it's worth to check them as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you are right. So I've just solved by adding &time parameter as from_time/to_time format.